# Bind Jquery Datepicker and Search value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I have a webpage with jquery datepicker and an input field with jquery autocomplete APIs. the Auto complete works well and so is the datepicker independently. But I want to bind the date. I want to perform a search based on these two values on mysql database implementing ajax to return JSON; I am completely confused as i have two events generating data and i want to send them at once. Can someone kindly point me in the right direction please.
 my idea:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("searchbtn").focus(function(){
          $.post("ajaxsearch.php",{serachterm: "#selectedterm".val(), timestamp:"#selectedDate".val() }, function(data){
              alert("Sent!")
          });
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("searchbtn").click(function(){
      $.post("ajaxsearch.php",{serachterm: $("#selectedterm").val(), timestamp:$("#selectedDate").val() }, function(data){
          alert("Sent!")
      });
  });
 });
```

make sure that, selectedterm & selectedDate are the corresponding id's of inputs